# How to tell the exact number of significant digits of a numerical approximation?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

My numerical analysis book uses the same definition for significant digits as stated in this post [Why does relative error give number of correct digits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180252/why-does-relative-error-give-number-of-correct-digits?rq=1)

[image]

My question is how can I tell when the number of significant digits that $x$ and $y$ agree on is exactly $t$ or $t+1$? I can't think of a case where they agree on $t+1$ significant digits

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $\beta=10$ so we are working with decimal numbers.

and as an example suppose $y=1.0002\, x$ for $x>0$.

Then $\frac{|x-y|}{|x|}=0.0002$ and $10^{-4} < 0.0002 \le 10^{-3}$.

If $x=8$ then $y=8.0016$ which agrees with $x$ to $3$ significant digits.

If $x=2$ then $y=2.0004$ which agrees with $x$ to $4$ significant digits.

Whether it is $t$ or $t+1$ significant digits depends on the circumstances of the case, but if the first significant digit  of $x$ and the first significant digit of $\frac{|x-y|}{|x|}$ both being small makes $t+1$ more likely

Comment: Is it possible to modify the defintion as to have an lower bound in the interval that tells me that the number of significant digits is always t?

Comment: Not easily.  Better to say "the number of significant digits is at least $t$" and if you get an extra one then that is a bonus

Comment: So on a per-case basis, I should count the digits that COINCIDE , but it is no always possible, since I saw an example in the answer of this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149580/number-of-correct-digits-of-an-expression?rq=1, which is actually for the concept of number of correct decimals, but I know is the similar with significant digit... , the difference bwing that for the number of correct decimals the absolute value is used instead

Comment: So since an approximation may even have not  coincident digits, the definition would yield t, but not being able to count explicitly the coincident digits, how would I distinguish between t or t+1 in that case?